# Javascript - nested arrays transformed to array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a nested array data structure like this -

```
var arrays = [
        [
            ['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']
        ],
        [
            ['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']
        ]
    ];
```

and I need to transform this into an array of objects  -

```
[
        {firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role: 'clerk'},
        {firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins', age: 36, role: 'manager'}
    ]..



    My code below gives- 

    function objectArray(arr) {
      var obj1 ={};
      var empData=[];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if (Array.isArray(arr[i]))
                { 
                  arr[i].reduce(function(acc,prd){
                   // console.log(prd);
                       console.log(acc.key=prd[0],acc.Value=prd[1]);//--> output shown below
                       return acc;
                  },{});
                }
        }
    }

     var returnArrayOfObjs = objectArray(arrays);
     var empData = [];
     empData.push(returnArrayOfObjs);
     console.log(empData);
```

*The above log statement gives me an [undefined] as shown below in my output -*

### The output I get is as below - What am I doing wrong? Pls help!

```
firstName Joe
lastName Blow
age 42
role clerk
firstName Mary
lastName Jenkins
age 36
role manager
[undefined]
```

Comment: You are not storing the result of `arr[i].reduce` anywhere.

Comment: @T4rk1n Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Iterate the array with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) each sub array to an object.

```js
const arr = [[["firstName","Joe"],["lastName","Blow"],["age",42],["role","clerk"]],[["firstName","Mary"],["lastName","Jenkins"],["age",36],["role","manager"]]];

const result = arr.map((subArr) => subArr.reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
  obj[key] = value;
  return obj;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: +1 for map and reduce...Thanks! I am using reduce too.. but don't know why the final object is not an object but just strings!

Comment: @sunnysideup - In your code, inside the `reduce` you are not attaching the key and value correctly to the object, and you don't store the result of the reduce. So all the `reduce` does is `console.log` the strings you see.

Comment: thank you v much! so obj.key and obj.Value does not really work.. we need to use bracket notation to attach the key values?

Comment: Indeed. You have to assign the value to a key on the object `obj[key] = value`.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a `forEach()` solution but `map()` / `reduce()` is probably more elegant so I upvoted @OriDrori :) Just posting this for comparison.

```js
var arrays = [[['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],
        [['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]
    ];

var rst = [];
    
 arrays.forEach(function(item){
    var obj = {};
    item.forEach(function( subitem, index ){
     obj[ subitem[0] ] = subitem[1]
    });
    rst.push(obj);
 });
 
 console.log( rst );
```

Comment: Thanks for the UV :)

Comment: Thanks @sauntimo.. I really do like forEach.. easier to read...was just trying to see why my reduce is failing..  thanks for your quick response!

Comment: just a quick clarification.. in the above forEach are we not creating the obj every time.. meaning for every item...

Comment: Yeah, `obj` is var scoped to that function, think of it as a temporary store before we put the populated object in to the array